VPS server %steal reason
We have VPS hosting for our e-commerce website which use hostinger service. The server specification is 32 GB RAM with 8cpu. Now when there is only user coming up in the website also not getting website properly running.
When I checked the cpu usage I can see %steal is 90% , the service provider say it's an dedicated server for us only but how the cpu getting shared.
Also I found some thing noticed is - when I suspend the main domain the steal% going to zero when the time I activate main domain the %steal is going to 90 and all
Any one know what could be the reason?
Tried optimising the php code from wordpress and reboot the server. All same result . whenever I activate the main domain %steal going up suddenly to 93%.
All the server setup is done by us only not by hostinger. And I have hired a devops team and they tried too much and not able to resolve it and they are saying upgrade to new plan.
why I have to upgrade if the problem persist with one user as well?
